# Getting this warning, "NSWindow has detected an excessive live window count of 101" in Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode, nswindow

Im trying to make a game with Xcode in c++ using SDL2. Ive been getting different errors but this is the latest

[Window] WARNING: NSWindow has detected an excessive live window count of 101. Window 0x5679 of class 'SDLWindow' created after passing the threshold of 100. This window is not necessarily the cause, and this warning will only be shown once per window class. (
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5a821c -[NSWindow _setWindowNumber:] + 800
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5d5bbe _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 435
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5d40b8 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 1121
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5a72f8 -[NSWindow _commonInitFrame:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 800
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5a6ae2 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1193
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d5a6633 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff2d8390d8 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:] + 52
    7   SDL2                                0x00000001003d9de7 SDL2 + 237031
    8   SDL2                                0x000000010043d65a SDL2 + 644698
    9   BTLB                                0x00000001000019e9 _ZN4Game4initEv + 73
    10  BTLB                                0x0000000100001672 main + 82
    11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff678032e5 start + 1
)

here is my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

Game *game = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    game = new Game;

    while(game->init())
    {
        game->run();
    }

    delete game;
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef Game_h
#define Game_h
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2_image/SDL_image.h"

#define FPS_DELAY 500

#include "Robin.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game(){};

    bool init();
    void run();

private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    SDL_Texture* texture;

    bool running;

    Robin* robin;
    //Snevil* snevil;
    //Level* level;

    unsigned int lastTick, fpsTick, fps, frameCount;

    void handleEvents();
    void update(float delta);
    void render(float delta);
    void clean();

    void NewGame();

};


#endif /* Game_h */
```

Game.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    window = 0;
    renderer = 0;
}


bool Game::init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Big Trouble in Little Birthday", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Error creating window:" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if(!renderer)
    {
        std::cout << "Error creating renderer:" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("FILL");
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    lastTick = SDL_GetTicks();
    fpsTick = lastTick;
    fps = 0;
    frameCount = 0;

    return true;
}

void Game::run()
{
    robin = new Robin(renderer);


    while(running)
    {
        handleEvents();

        unsigned int curTick = SDL_GetTicks();
        float delta = (curTick - lastTick) / 1000.0f;

        if(curTick - fpsTick >= FPS_DELAY)
        {
            fps = frameCount * (1000.0f / (curTick - fpsTick));
            fpsTick = curTick;
            frameCount = 0;
            char buf[100];
            std::snprintf(buf, 100, "Big Trouble in Little Birthday (fps: %u)", fps);

            SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, buf);
        }
        else
        {
            frameCount++;
        }
        lastTick = curTick;

        update(delta);
        render(delta);
    }

    delete robin;

    clean();
    SDL_Quit();

}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;

    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                SDL_Quit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::update(float delta)
{
    robin->update(delta);
}

void Game::render(float delta)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    robin->update(delta);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::NewGame()
{

}
```

Entity.h

```
#ifndef Entity_h
#define Entity_h

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2_image/SDL_image.h"

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

    virtual ~Entity(){}

    float x, y, width, height;

    virtual void update(float delta);
    virtual void render(float delta);

    bool Collides(Entity* other);

protected:
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
};

#endif /* Entity_h */
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    this->renderer = renderer;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    width = 1;
    height = 1;
}

void Entity::update(float delta)
{

}

void Entity::render(float delta)
{

}

bool Entity::Collides(Entity* other)
{
    if(x + width > other ->x && x < other->x + other->width && y + height > other->y && y < other->y + other->height)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Robin.h

```
#ifndef Robin_h
#define Robin_h
#include "Entity.h"

class Robin : public Entity
{
public:
    Robin(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    ~Robin();

    void update(float delta);
    void render(float delta);

private:
    SDL_Texture* texture;

};
#endif /* Robin_h */
```

Robin.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Robin.h"

Robin::Robin(SDL_Renderer* renderer) : Entity(renderer)
{
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("/Users/noah/Desktop/BTLB/assets/Robin.png");
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    width = 16;
    height = 16;

}

Robin::~Robin()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}

void Robin::update(float delta)
{

}

void Robin::render(float delta)
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = (int)(x + 0.5f);
    rect.y = (int)(y + 0.5f);
    rect.w = width;
    rect.h = height;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, 0, &rect);
}
```

Comment: The main while loop is calling `game->init()` as the loop condition.  This is creating a new game window.

Comment: so what should it be calling?

Comment: So I changed the while statement in main to an if statement and it fixed the error but the window doesn't pop up